# statsmodel ARMA function is incompatiable with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have got a data set with records in the interval of 30 seconds, I am trying to do forecast prediction using ARMA function from time series module. Due to data privacy, I have used random data to reproduce the error

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = np.random.rand(100000)
data_index = date_range('2013-5-26', periods = len(data), freq='30s')
data = np.array(data)
data_series = Series(data, index = data_index)
model = sm.tsa.ARMA(data_series,(1,0)).fit()
```

My package versions:
Python version 2.7.3
pandas version 0.11.0
statsmodels version 0.5.0

The main error message is as follows(I omitted some):

```
ValueError        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-0f57c74f0fc9> in <module>()

6 data = np.array(data)
7 data_series = Series(data, index = data_index)
----> 8 model = sm.tsa.ARMA(data_series,(1,0)).fit()

...........

...........

ValueError: freq 30S not understood
```

It seems to me ARMA does not support the date format generated by pandas? If I remove freq option in date_range, then this command will again not work for large series since the year will go well beyond pandas limit.

Anyway to get around? Thanks

Update:
OK, using data_series.values will work, but next, how do I do the prediction? my data_index is from [2013-05-26 00:00:00, ..., 2013-06-29 17:19:30]

```
prediction = model.predict('2013-05-26 00:00:00', '2013-06-29 17:19:30', dynamic=False)
```

still give me an error

I know prediction = model.predict() could go through and generate whole sequence prediction and then I can match, but overall it is not that convenient.

Comment: This should probably be a github issue: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues

Comment: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/456 this is with an older version of pandas, FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this freq doesn't give back an offset from pandas for some reason, and we need an offset to be able to use the dates for anything. It looks like a pandas bug/not implemented to me.

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import get_offset
get_offset('30s')
```

Perhaps we could improve the error message though.

[**Edit** We don't really need the dates except for adding them back in for convenience in prediction, so you can still estimate the model by using data_series.values.]

Comment: OK, using data_series.values will work, but next, how do I do the prediction? my data_index is from [2013-05-26 00:00:00, ..., 2013-06-29 17:19:30] 
prediction = model.predict('2013-05-26 00:00:00', '2013-06-29 17:19:30', dynamic=False) give me an error also

Comment: Yeah, if don't give a dates index, you can't use dates to predict. You'll have to use index values, which is admittedly confusing. If you really only want one-step ahead in-sample prediction, you can just omit the start and end `model.predict()`. That's the default. See the docstring for predict.